# SQLite Error: No such Column

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, xamarin

**When trying to run the App, I get the Error:

> SQLite Error: No such Column: ImageName

It show me the Error at the Line at getItems() where it says:

> var r = contents.ExecuteReader ();

Anyone knows where my mistake is??

**

```
if (!exists) {
            connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + dbPath);

            connection.Open ();
            var commands = new[] {
                "CREATE TABLE [Items] (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, Date NTEXT, 
                                      Amount NTEXT, Supplier NTEXT, 
                                      ImageName NTEXT, AdditionalInfo NTEXT);"
            };
            foreach (var command in commands) {
                using (var c = connection.CreateCommand ()) {
                    c.CommandText = command;
                    var i = c.ExecuteNonQuery ();
                }
            }
        } else {
            // already exists, do nothing. 
        }
        Console.WriteLine (output);
    }
    /// <summary>Convert from DataReader to Note object</summary>
    Note FromReader (SqliteDataReader r) {
        var t = new Note ();
        t.ID = Convert.ToInt32 (r ["_id"]);
        t.Date = r ["Date"].ToString ();
        t.Amount = r ["Amount"].ToString ();
        t.Supplier = r ["Supplier"].ToString ();
        t.ImageName = r ["ImageName"].ToString ();
        t.AdditionalInfo = r ["AdditionalInfo"].ToString ();
        return t;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Note> GetItems ()
    {
        var tl = new List<Note> ();

        lock (locker) {
            connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + path);
            connection.Open ();
            using (var contents = connection.CreateCommand ()) {
                contents.CommandText = "SELECT [_id], [Date], 
                                               [Amount], [Supplier], [ImageName],
                                               [AdditionalInfo]  from [Items]"; 
                var r = contents.ExecuteReader ();
                while (r.Read ()) {
                    tl.Add (FromReader(r));
                }
            }
            connection.Close ();
        }
        return tl;
    }
```

Comment: The SQLite.NET component will give you an ORM layer so you don't have to hand-write SQL.  Have you tried that?  I would also inspect the db file created by your app to verify the ImageName column is present and named like you expect.

Comment: sorry but I'm new Databases, this is my first try. 
What exactly do I have to do?

Comment: http://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net